# Is Spotify Android API audio delivered in raw PCM?

Tags: android, audio, spotify, pcm, drm

I am wanting to write a Spotify Android plug-in to perform audio pre-processing prior to playback.

Judging by the documentation for com.spotify.sdk.android.player.AudioController.onAudioDataDelivered:

> samples - 16-bit PCM data. The buffer contains sampleCount samples, whereby each sample contains the data for a single audio channel.

and the now deprecated libspotify int( * sp_session_callbacks::music_delivery):

> [in]  frames  Points to raw PCM data as described by format

It appears that the Android onAudioDataDelivered call above would receive raw PCM data (non DRM encoded).

Could anyone confirm this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's raw PCM , you can hook into the PCM playback with the Android SDK.

Comment: How do you do this? I can't find any working examples